# manejo de conexiones del Modem mediante Java

Tags: java, clase

Necesito saber si hay alguna(s) clase(s) que pueda obtener propiedades de las conexiones de los dispositivos conectados a la red del modem.

Comment: Asumiendo que hablas de algun tipo de router wifi o algo similar, debes averiguar en la documentación del fabricante del modem a ver si expone alguna API que te permita obtener esos datos. Si no es el caso, siempre puedes "parsear" la interface web para obtener los datos directamente del html, es un poco brusco pero efectivo.

Answer (score 1):

No me queda muy claro lo que pretendes hacer pero te dejo un código que recorre las conexiónes en red y te muestra los ips de los ordenadores conectados al momento bajo un rango de ips

```
public void checkHosts(String subnet){
   int timeout=1000;
   for (int i=1;i<255;i++){
       String host=subnet + "." + i;
       if (InetAddress.getByName(host).isReachable(timeout)){
           System.out.println(host + " Encontrado");
       }
   }
}
```

Para la subred (192.168.0.1-254)

```
checkHosts("192.168.0");
```

Una vez obtenido un Host podrías consultar sus propiedades

```
// InetAddress address = InetAddress.byName ... 


System.out.println("Host Address: "+ address.getHostAddress());
System.out.println("Host Name: "+ address.getHostName());
System.out.println("CanonicalHostName: "+ address.getCanonicalHostName());
System.out.println("Address: "+ address.getAddress());
System.out.println("LocalHost: "+ address.getLocalHost());
System.out.println("LoopbackAddress: "+ address.getLoopbackAddress());
```

Comment: Trato de hacer una aplication que pueda obtener los dispositivos conectados a mi modem, asi como las propiedads de cada uno(por ejemplo, modelo del dispositivo) y administrar esas conexiones

Comment: La unica forma de administrar conexiónes en el modem (ya que este tiene un pequeño firmware algunos un mini sistema operativo) es vía telnet no puedes administrarlo como si fuese un teclado o mouse, podrías usar librerías que te permitan usar Sockets de Java para ello pero no conozco nada de mas alto nivel.

Comment: Esta bien, ¿Con C++ se podria hacer esto mas directamente?

Comment: De igual manera, claro tendrías mas herramientas de bajo nivel pero de igual manera la estrategia seria por sockets hacer una conexión y administrarlo vía comandos, es como querer controlar una pc desde otra, la única forma seria creando una sesión shell.